# iOS 11 Tableview Selection

Tags: uitableview, ios11, xcode9, swift4

I worked on tableview functionality so that when a tableview cell is selected, the tableview reloads and displays a checkmark in the selected row. The selected row was not highlighted and didn't allow multiple rows to be selected.

With iOS 11, it stopped working as expected. I would like the selected row to display a checkmark. In addition, the background of selected row should not be highlighted and not allow multiple rows to be selected.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let clientCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientCell", for: indexPath)
    clientCell.selectionStyle = .none

    if selectedIdxPath == indexPath.row {
        clientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    } else {
        clientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    return clientCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIdxPath = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your delegate methods :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let clientCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientCell", for: indexPath)
    clientCell.selectionStyle = .none

    if selectedIdxPath == indexPath.row {
        clientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    } else {
        clientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    return clientCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIdxPath = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```